# WCF Rest service and Auth schemes

Tags: wcf, rest

I have been able to create a nice WCF service for an integration project that can return results in plain xml, json and soap. This works great up until the point where I start to implement security. The built in ws security features in wcf services are bypassed when using WebHttpBindings which work well with:

```
<webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
```

and

```
[OperationContract()]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetSomething/{someID}/{anotherID}?somethingElse={somethingElse}")]
SomeResponse GetSomething(string someID,string anotherID, DateTime somethingElse)
```

I enjoyed playing with my first restful api but alas I need to finish a project and a requirement is to include a secure authentication policy. I am not required to return the results as json, nor must it be a rest service, but this has stoked my curiosity.

...any good ideas pertaining to authentication strategies/WCF REST services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want clientCredentialType="Certificate" or "Windows"

```
<webHttpBinding>
  <binding name ="RestSSL">
    <security mode ="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType= "Windows" />
    </security>
  </binding>                
</webHttpBinding>
```

If you use certificate, you'll need to also set the serviceBehavior's certificateValidationMode to something like PeerTrust, ChainTrust, etc. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.x509certificatevalidationmode.aspx

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="1048576"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <!-- Please note: the app pool will need an identity with access to this cert-->
        <serviceCertificate findValue="myCertSubject.myDomain.com"
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            storeName="My"
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally most of the people tend to use OAuth, when securing a restful wcf service. OAuth is an open protocol to allow secure API authentication in a simple and standard method from desktop and web applications. It allows a client to provide a consumer key that identifies the client which has to be sent for each service call. The information is sent as part of HTTP Authorization header. Download the OAuth Class from [here](https://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/csharp/OAuthBase.cs)

For implementation detail check out this [Code Project Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/372422/Secure-WCF-RESTful-service-using-OAUTH)

Comment: I have implemented OpenID for SSO in the past. if the OAuth lib is as straightforward then this is prob the ticket

Comment: I do not understand, what do you mean by " prob the ticket"